# Extra space between special characters ç and a in Força

Tags: css

I have a problem that i can't find any solution anywhere.

Bellow is the code in my `CSS`

```
label[for="username"]::after {
  content: 'Se você é da Força de Vendas, digite seu CPF.';
}
```

When browser render my `CSS`, the code changes and i have this result bellow:

```
label[for="username"]::after {
  content: 'Se voc\EA \E9 da For\E7 a de Vendas, digite seu CPF.';
}
```

The change above render this in my browser:

`Se você é do Forç a de Vendas, digite seu CPF.`

Any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Solve what exactly? Your initial text seems to be at the end rendered correctly. The browser (in the middle step) re-encodes the values

Comment: @Ron it took me a bit too, but it's a space in `Força` - between the `ç` and the `a`

Comment: Ah, I missed that :)

Comment: Yeah, I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor. My problem is exactly in the word ```Força```

Comment: Is there a `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` section of the HTML?

Comment: Yes @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
label[for="username"]::after {
  content: 'Se voc\0000EA  \0000E9  da For\0000E7 a de Vendas, digite seu CPF.';
}
```

This usually would work within HTML the way you have tried. but within CSS it needs to be UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoded as the prefixes `&` or `\` are not rendered in `CSS content`

Here are few references:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have tried to insert ```@charset 'UTF-16';``` in my ```CSS``` file and ```<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css; encoding=UTF-16" />``` in my ```HTML``` file, and i have the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: I tested the above in codepen, now I created a local html page, with CSS inline, and I am unable to replicate your issue. What browser/version are you having issues with?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 76.0b8 (64-bits)

Comment: Do you have a live website where I can test? I uploaded my example here: http://xcc.me/chars.html let me know what is different, or better provide some way I can see your setup, so I can mimic it better to reproduce the issue..

Comment: You can test it in https://auth.compra-agora.webpremios.digital/login?client_id=2ng9n3e7g1ihqcelrsovp2vsbm&nonce=7a7707ab39214e779269baa361617dea&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcompra-agora.webpremios.digital%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=token&scope=profile%20email%20openid%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin%20webpremios.campaigns%2F50635&state=ed59b5b0ee42441494f1e3e012a8089e.

Comment: ok, so I see that https://auth-statics.compra-agora.webpremios.digital/static/css/bundle.0597876d.css itself contains the `Se voc\EA \E9` encoded this way.. so this is either coming from the Editor that you are using, or is somehow packed/generated by react... try within that CSS file to literally type out `'Se você é da Força de Vendas, digite seu CPF.'` , and make sure that once you do, you open https://auth-statics.compra-agora.webpremios.digital/static/css/bundle.0597876d.css in browser and you are seeing what you typed. And once you see it ok there, try to reload your page and replicate?

Comment: So, at the first time, i've typed exactly ```'Se você é da Força de Vendas, digite seu CPF.'``` without any unicode char. The css file generated by Sass was with the same text but in my browser (Firefox) i had this issue. I've tested it in Chrome too and the same issue happens. When i change the text in browser's console, the issue disapear.

Comment: well, I still see the `Se voc\EA \E9` characters if I view https://auth-statics.compra-agora.webpremios.digital/static/css/bundle.0597876d.css ... was this .css file regenerated? Can you make a test and now go into that CSS file, and in place edit the sentences (it is in two places in that file) .. It might be the SCSS that generates this file to wronlgy encode it... but I am sure that if you have it proper in the output CSS file, it will render properly...

Comment: Yes it was. Here is my part of my css file that was generated:
```[data-campaign] .form-field label[for="username"]::after {
  content: "Se você é da Força de Vendas, digite seu CPF.";
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
}```

Comment: Yeah, but if you view: https://auth-statics.compra-agora.webpremios.digital/static/css/bundle.0597876d.css (which is the already generated file), you should see what you inserted, as per your last comment, and not `content:"Se voc\EA    \E9    da For\E7  a` , that is what I am saying... go and edit it in that file manually. And if you did, then it's your Editor that is not working with UTF-8 properly... try another editor, like `vim` for example..

Comment: I've made the modification. And still there the same problem. I'm using VS Code to write my css code and i'm using Watch my Sass extension to generate the CSS file from Sass. In the CSS file i have the text without any unicode character but i don't know what happens with my browser that change this part of text. I tried another editor and again, no solution

Comment: I still see the encoded parts in https://auth-statics.compra-agora.webpremios.digital/static/css/bundle.91fe1fc6.css ... until those are there, I believe the browser will render them as they are (not properly)

Comment: Ok, i think that i'm breaking head a lot with this. I will change this for a HTML text a forget this issue. @Ron Thank you very much for try to help me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a long discussion about how to solve this problem, i've found one solution:

Delete the text from CSS and write it in HTML. I don't know what motivates this issue, but if you have the same situation with accentuation text in CSS, remove it and do it in HTML.

You will waste less time and have more time to do other things.

So, that's it.